# Does "Java Client for GAE Channels" work with libgdx for both Android and iOS?

Tags: google-app-engine, libgdx, channel-api

Can I use this with libgdx on both Android and iOS:

[Java Client for GAE Channels](http://masl.cis.gvsu.edu/2012/01/31/java-client-for-appengine-channels/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is YES, it is possible to use GAE Channels with libgdx on both Desktop, Android and iOS, but it involves some dependency tweaking.